# Spring Boot 2 how to change startup behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, installation

do not judge this question) I want to implement WEB installer for my Spring Boot application, and very interesting moment is that my application plays 2 role: Installer and Backend(Application). When i first run my app i need to tell Spring to not initialize particular beans(Hibernate(while startup application must not to be failed to start because database may not exist), ActiveMq and others beans that will be added in installation process) and show some html pages with installation guide. Also i need to prevent access to endpoints where some logic with database occurs. When installation finished i will create new application.properties or some other file with settings and i tell Spring to initialize all required beans with Hibernate, ActiveMQ and others. Maybe i will make restart of application and new behaviour that based on installation will occur. And in next starts my application will not show installation guide. To simplify the question: I need to change startup behaviour of Spring Boot Application. For fun i can give an example with human: I need to make human live with no organs, and this human will live very good, and if i want i can add organs to human and he will be live very well))

Comment: That's not easy to accomplish. Are you sure this is the best way to solve whatever problem you are having? Alas, not knowing why you think you need this, we can not point out easier alternatives ...

Comment: I would (but not exactly sure how to do that) create a separate `applicationContext` with hibernate and everything that depends on it. That child `applicationContext` would be loaded on demand by... whatever needs it (maybe it could be a lazy init bean in the parent `applicationContext`). (/me trying not to judge why one would to that.)

Comment: sounds like a XY problem to me: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem (and of course we judge the question, that's what SO is about ;))

Comment: @meriton i cardinally changed question

Comment: There are a lot of conditional annotations in spring-boot-autoconfigure jar. Take a look at `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation or `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingClass` or investigate another ones in the same package. Might some of them helps you

Comment: Or implement custom condition. Check @Profile annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @Profile annotation. Check this link: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/

Comment: great answer sir! I believe that your answer will help us with this task!